# Cipher suite priority

Tags: encryption, rsa, tls, dsa

I've been tasked with defining a list of cipher suites to use.

The requirements for the cipher suites are the following:

- Symmetric Algorithm: AES-256
- Key Exchange: ECDH P-384, DH 3072-bit, RSA 3072-bit
- Key Authentication: ECDSA P-384, RSA 3072-bit
- Hash Algorithm: SHA-384

Here is the list I've come up with (in prioritized order):

1. TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x00C02C)
2. TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0x00C024)
3. TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x00C030)
4. TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0x00C028)
5. TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x00009F)
6. TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x00C02E)
7. TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0x00C026)
8. TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x00C032)
9. TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0x00C02A)
10. TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x00009D)
11. TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x0000A1)

Would you say I've made the correct prioritization of the cipher suites? Are any of these ciphers considered weak?

Comment: Uhm, why do you prioritize CBC over GCM?

Comment: I'd say [1] prefer GCM over CBC, [2] prefer ECDHE over ECDH over DH [3] prefer ECDSA over RSA.

Comment: @SEJPM, looks like a typo. 0x00C02C uses GCM. 4ndr345
, could you clarify?

Comment: @otus A typo indeed. Edited the question to correct the mistake.

Comment: @puzzlepalace In regards to Key exchange, would you prefer DHE over ECDH or the other way around? And where would you rate RSA in there?

Comment: I'd prefer DHE over ECDH if the groups have comparable security parameters as you get forward secrecy from DHE. RSA would be towards the bottom with DH, for a detailed comparison of those two see [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/35521/81272).

Comment: Isn't this question primarily opinion based? There aren't obviously weak modes, maybe except for CBC...

Comment: @axapaxa To a certain degree, it certainly is. I've conducted some research and there aren't much support for some of these ciphers. Additionally, I'll probably try to steer away from TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 as Windows does not support ephemeral DH key size above 1024.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are all fine and the order seems reasonable as well. It is a judgement call which part you think is most likely to fail. I would use your order of preference for the elliptic curve algorithms. GCM vs. CBC is a case of which you find more likely to be badly implemented.

If the requirements are not enforced upon you, I would consider adding in P-256. It should be as strong as 3072-bit RSA, and it at least used to be slightly more widely supported than P-384 – I have not seen recent numbers though.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've decided to scrap most of the non-ephemeral ciphers as all services I have tested against that support these options also supports the ephemeral variants. I've also removed DHE as the services that will implement this list does not support DHE > 1024/2048 (my requirement is 3072).

Here's my final list (in prioritized order):
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384